# How can I set percentage height for a div inside a div with min-height?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with `min-height=100;` with a `div` inside it.

Now I want to use `height=80%;` for inner `div` but it doesn't work.
Please check the html and css section:

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.outer{
  width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  background-color:gray;
  border:5px solid red;
}
.inner{
  height:80%;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">

</div>
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">

 </div>
</div>
```

It works when I use `height` instead of `min-height` for outer `div` but I can't use `height` because the height of the content of inner `div` is not fixed.

**For fiddlers:**
jsfiddle (updated with 3d outer div that have more than 100% height):

https://jsfiddle.net/mr_seven/d9ubjpe4/9/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved with some jQuery codes.

```
$(".inner").parent().addClass('fixedheight');
```

CSS:

```
fixedheight{
  height:100%;
}
```

Now all of my outer `div's` will have `min-height=100%;` and if one of them (or more than one) have inner `div`, the outer `div` will have fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `height: 80%`. After all, you're setting the min-height to 100%, which is also the max-height. So, it seems slightly pointless. Also, you need to give your div a width.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it better to play with `padding-bottom` instead of struggling with `min-height`?

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.outer{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height:80%;
  background-color:yellow;
  border:5px solid red;
}
.inner{
  height:80%;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">

</div>
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">
 
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need that min-height. because there is lots of outer div in my page and their content doesn't have fixed height.

Comment: @Sadegh So, please check this version. It uses `min-height`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

HTML:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.outer {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner {
  background-color: red;
  height: 80%;
}
```

CSS:

```
<div class="outer">
  outer
  <div class="inner">
    inner
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay but as I said I can't use fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this..[Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/d9ubjpe4/10/)

```
<div class="outer">

</div>
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">

 </div>
</div>
```

css

```
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.outer{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  background-color:gray;
  border:5px solid red;
  display: table;
}
.inner{
  height:80%;
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All I need is height of inner div to be 80% of page height.

Comment: when my inner content is more than 100% height of the page.(the outer div is not just for this div. and If I add another class to this outer div I will loose flexibility of my template.)